# Is there a word for food that's gone 'bad', but is still edible?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word in the English language for food that has gone 'bad', but is still edible?

Some examples would be honey that has crystalized, ice cream that has ice all over it, etc. The foods aren't in their normal eating conditions, and thus maybe are said to have 'gone bad', but they are still edible.

To me, 'gone bad' suggested they are not edible and is synonymous with *expired*. The foods can be eaten since honey can be heated to decrystallize it, the ice in ice cream can be scraped off, etc.

Comment: Was talking to a guy this PM who had been on a hurricane relief effort and had the problem that the bottled water they had was past it's "use by" date and hence could not be distributed through a government-sponsored program.

Comment: Food is always edible, even when it's gone bad. Technically everything is edible.

Comment: @HotLicks: Why would water even _have_ a use-by date?

Comment: @Sean Maybe it has something to do with the concentration of bacteria. I don't think bottled water starts out completely sterile.

Comment: @sean It's not the water, it's the plastic bottle. After a while some of the compounds in the plastic leach into the water making it less than optimal as a drink.

Comment: @DanielTate Fwiw, edible actually carries the sense "fit to be eaten", not just "able to be shoved into the esophagus".

Comment: @Sean - One theory put forward is that, since the water was bottled by a beer manufacturer, they reflexively put a date on it.

Comment: Cheese.   vinegar.   yogurt.

Comment: By definition, **bad** is... BAD, and bad food is inedible.  You're asking about **old but still edible** food.

Comment: crystallized honey tastes better than liquid honey...

Comment: Crystallized honey is just as good as the liquid one. Many prefer it this way, and it's common to find it in shops. It has the advantage of not dripping off your toast.

Comment: In the UK (as I suppose in most places) packaged food which can deteriorate, has a "sell by" and/or a "use by" date stamped on the package. Most food is perfectly edible long after the "use by" date. I heard of one person who had made a considerable fortune out of dealing, perfectly legally, in food beyond its "sell by date". (As long as the food is fit to eat, there is no law against selling it.) And from what I was told plenty of organisations involved in catering were quite happy to buy it at a significant discount from its normal price. Such food is described as "out of date" food.

Comment: Makes me think of AGED meat.

Comment: @Muze Well yes. Some foods are deliberately aged - not to make them "bad" but better e.g. pheasant is hung, and various cheeses are aged.

Answer (score 60):

***[Stale](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/stale)*** suggests the idea of food which is no longer fresh but still edible:

> no longer new or fresh, usually as a result of being kept for too long:
>
> - The bread/biscuits/cake had gone stale.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: Stale is only for bread and bread-like things, such as cake and cookies, I'd say.

Comment: @HemiPoweredDrone generally yes, but I think it can be used by extension for any food that gets undesirably dry or hard after a time. If someone described honey as "stale," I'd know what they meant.

Comment: @HemiPoweredDrone: Also beer and news, which makes for a nice thought on what's the bread of our lifes... :-D

Comment: I agree, I think the meaning of *stale* has broadened to mean "past its best", without being too specific about the properties.  This is certainly the case in non-food contexts, so I don't see why it couldn't be applied in food contexts too.

Comment: `Stale` implies "not very nice" as opposed to `gone bad` which strongly implies "will make you unwell"

Comment: @DevSolar if beer is described as 'stale' I'm afraid it becomes indelibly associated in my mind with the fluid a horse produces when it stales. https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/stale

Comment: @JustinLardinois Hm, I disagree. If someone called honey "stale," I'd have no idea what they meant. I certainly wouldn't think they just meant it had crystallized.

Comment: I can't imagine anyone calling freezer burned ice cream "stale".

Answer (score 41):

If it is still edible but not in the state that its makers would have preferred it is "past its best".

Although the word "stale" conveys the same meaning with some foods, such as bread/biscuits/cake, it does not do so with all foods, such as, say, cheese.

I think it all depends on the foodstuff in question. If it is fruit then "over-ripe" might do

> passed beyond maturity or ripeness toward decay (Merriam-Webster).

And yet, my Aunt was fond of medlars. That is a fruit that is eaten only after it passed beyond maturity towards decay.

And what about well-hung pheasant or grouse?

That all leads me to the view that no single word will encompass all the ideas that the OP has in mind.

Comment: "past its best" fits perfectly, for my money.

Comment: 'Past' to me implies that the item cannot be in its prime/ideal state again. This isn't the case for heating honey to decrystalize it for example. It's not past it's prime state, it's just not in its prime or ideal state.

Comment: Stale can be used with cheese, see [stale hard cheese](https://www.wikihow.com/Rescue-Stale-Hard-Cheese)

Comment: More common (to me) variations of this would include "*past its sell-by date*", "*past its prime*", "*past its expiration*".  The [theme song](https://genius.com/Eric-idle-one-foot-in-the-grave-lyrics) to the British sitcom "One Foot in the Grave" was full of phrases like this, but they're mostly UK-specific and also apply more to people than food, but some might work.

Comment: @Dave  Certainly not in this case - crystallised honey is just as edible as runny honey, hence most stores will also stock "thick honey" or "set honey" which is pre-crystallised.

Comment: Does "salvageable" fit? This doesn't necessarily dictate that one loses some of the food, or not, or that the quality has been reduced - but it does mean retrieval is possible.

Comment: I've very often heard this shortened to "past" (or "passed"), which has the virtue of also being short for "past its best-used-by date". The milk is past.

Answer (score 26):

**off**

See meanings 2 and 4:

> Adjective: **off**  (óf)
>
> 1. Not in operation or operational
>
>    "the oven is off"; "the lights are off"
> 2. **Below a satisfactory level**
>
>    "an off year for tennis"; "his performance was off"
> 3. (of events) no longer planned or scheduled
>
>    "the wedding is definitely off";
>
>    - cancelled [Brit, Cdn], canceled [US]
> 4. **In an unpalatable state**
>
>    "off milk";
>
>    - sour, turned
> 5. Not performing or scheduled for duties
>      "He's off every Tuesday"
>
> -- [WordWeb](https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=off)

As can be seen for #4, **unpalatable** is another term for what you describe:

> Adjective: **unpalatable**  (ún'pa-lu-tu-bul)
>
> 1. Not pleasant or acceptable to the taste or mind
>
>    "an unpalatable meal"; "unpalatable truths"; "unpalatable behaviour"
>
>    See also: brackish, distasteful, inedible, offensive, tasteless, unappetising [Brit], unappetizing, uneatable, unpleasant, unsavory [US], unsavoury [Brit, Cdn]
>
> Antonym: palatable

Comment: That's what I was thinking also, when I saw this Q. But doesn't 4)  imply something that also smells bad? i.e. bacteria and so _not_ safe to eat?

Comment: @Cascabel: Yes, it does mean that.  So only meaning 2 covers the OP's request.  e.g. "these oranges are a bit off, they need eating before they spoil".

Comment: @cascabel: No. *unpalatable* means *"Not pleasant or acceptable to the taste or mind: 'an unpalatable meal'; 'unpalatable truths'; 'unpalatable behavior'"*. (Also WordWeb as reference.) Not pleasant or acceptable does *not* mean not safe to eat.

Comment: (And the example given explicitly for #4 is *sour milk*, which is definitely not unsafe - it just tastes off/sour.)

Comment: This would have been mine. If it doesn't look too bad, I'd probably add a qualifier ("it looks/tastes a little off", or something like that).

Comment: I like _brackish_, as in, "Better put this honey in the microwave; it's gone brackish." Under its definitions for _brackish_, Wordnik lists "distasteful; unpalatable; unpleasant; **spoiled by mixture**; not appealing to the taste." Personally, I think that one word answers the OP's query better than any of the other suggestions on this page.

Answer (score 16):

The best all-purpose word is really **edible**, like @Vaelus noted on @Rob's answer. You don't use it to describe desirable food, just stuff that's barely passable. Speaking of which,

## [passable](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/138431)

is one possible word that hasn't been mentioned yet.

> **2.** Of adequate or acceptable quality; sufficient; satisfactory. In later use: just good enough to be acceptable.
>
> > 1893 June 12, *The Times*, p. 4:
> >
> > > Potatoes appear in eight departments... very good, 13 good, 17 satisfactory, 18 passable, six mediocre, and three bad. [*sic*]

Answer (score 11):

Another word might be suitable : **substandard**.

> : deviating from or falling short of a standard or norm: such as
>   a : of a quality lower than that prescribed by law
>   substandard housing

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/substandard)

> 1. Of less than the required or normal quality or size; of a lower standard than required, inferior.

[Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/193046?redirectedFrom=substandard#eid)

Comment: Adding **sub-par** as a similar phrase with an almost identical meaning.

Comment: These phrases do not imply that the item was once within acceptable specification but has now deteriorated.

Answer (score 8):

The most common phrase for this -- I remember from my Mum as a child -- was that the food was:

> **On its last legs**
>
> [cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on-its-last-legs) Something that is on its last legs is in such bad condition that it will soon be unable to work as it should

---

The key thing is described exactly the correct state of the food. It is **nearly** inedible, but it is still edible.

Unlike other phrases that just mention the food being substandard - and give no indication that it's become substandard over time - the focus here is the degradation; it is OK right now - but if it's left any longer it won't be.

Answer (score 7):

I say the item has passed its prime. 
Or the item is ***[past its prime](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/past+their+prime).***

Meaning it is not in optimal condition but hasn’t  reached a spoiled state yet.

Comment: I'd've spelt it *past* but either's good.

Comment: @lly    "has passed" or   "is past"  .  Gotta know your conjugations!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Not in the least. [Past is simply an alternative spelling of passed](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/138567). See also learned/t, dreamed/t, &c.

Comment: Past is never a verb @lly

Comment: @lly  First: it's not nice to put a link to a site which requires membership.  Next: If you bother to read the OED entry, I'm betting you will discover your alleged spelling alternative is centuries obsolete.

Comment: @Kris You're simply wrong, as already linked.

Comment: @Carl_Wittholft People are welcome to google elsewhere. It's still the gold standard English reference, and you misread it. What's obsolete is the spelling past to mean the present-tense verb pass.

Comment: https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2015/01/07/passed-past/. @lly

Answer (score 6):

A hypernym of freezer-burned ice cream and re-crystallized sugars is ***old***. It may be past its expiration date, *"but it's **still good**."*

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, this is not a single word, but I think it fits better than the other proposals so far:

**not at its best**

This fits the two examples you gave, of the crystallized honey and the ice cream with ice crystals.  It would also work for green beans that need a lot of trimming, slightly rubbery broccoli, slightly wilted lettuce, breaded chicken cutlets that were heated up three times and have gotten rather dried out and chewy.

Some alternatives with a similar flavor:

**seen better days**

**a little worse for wear**

**not the pick of the crop**

Some examples:

> These green beans have seen better days.
>
> This ice cream is not at its best.
>
> This lettuce is looking a little worse for wear.
>
> These peaches are not the pick of the crop.

There is no suggestion that any of these foods will do you any harm -- they're just suboptimal.

Well, I guess there you have a single word:

**suboptimal**

But it's not as colorful.

Answer (score 3):

Food spoilage refers to the action of bacteria or fungi (mold, yeast) that make the food go “bad”, ultimately dangerous to eat.

Food grading, on the other hand, is a question of quality and freshness. Food that is not fresh may suffer in flavor and texture, although it may be safe to eat. Nutrients may also be lost.

There are many processes (evaporation, melting, or oxidation) that may degrade foods; some changes can be reversed (e.g., crystallization), and the degraded part may be removed. You can get rid of crystals on ice cream, but the part that’s been melted will be degraded, although not necessarily spoiled.

So degraded (more specific than old) is a good term for this, although not what people would use in conversation.

Answer (score 2):

> Word for Food that's Gone 'Bad', but is Still Edible?

Which side of the line a definition sits can be the subject of some debate, it is cultural in north American English to separate the terms "good" and "bad" when referring to food, there is no overlap or middle ground.

Both culture and prosperity can play a role in definitions of something so important, it's both important to eat but in north American it's important that the quality be of a particular level, IE: not "bad", by a long stretch.

**[unwholesome](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unwholesome)** adjective
: detrimental to physical, mental, or moral well-being : unhealthy, unwholesome food

- "Health inspectors shut down several food stands that were using tainted and unwholesome meat."
- "A diet of fried foods and pizza is unwholesome."

You can bend the definition of one word either way, but there's no overlap, it doesn't mean the same thing. The ability to stretch one word to cover both extremes doesn't equate the meaning.

If food has gone bad it's not [edible](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/edible):

**edible** adjective
: fit to be eaten : eatable

**edible** noun
: something that is suitable or safe to eat : something edible

Food that is "bad" is by definition "no good" to eat, unless you wish to eat bad food.

Proverb: "Food you will not eat you do not boil.".

A lot also depends on culture and definition. One Roman proverb is "More die by food than famine.", another is: "Jejunus raro stomachus vulgaria temnit: a hungry stomach rarely despises common fare (also translated: the stomach that is rarely hungry despises common fare) (Horace)".

A couple of Filipino proverbs are: "There is no bad food in a famine." and "There is no bitter crust to a hungry person." A Catalonia proverb is: "In times of famine no bread is stale.". None of those proverbs make the food more or less edible, it is the state of hunger, the need, that makes one more tolerant of a lower standard.

Take for example [hákarl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A1karl) (a national dish of Iceland) and [hongeo-hoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hongeo-hoe) (Korean); which are cartilaginous fish that excrete uric acid through the skin, rather than by urinating as other animals do. These fish are simply buried and left to ferment, utilizing the ammonia as a preservative.

In the case of hákarl the meat of the Greenland shark is poisonous when fresh, due to a high content of urea and trimethylamine oxide, but may be consumed after being processed.

In the case of [surströmming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surstr%C3%B6mming), (Swedish for "sour herring"), just enough salt is used to prevent the raw herring from rotting. A fermentation process of at least six months gives the fish a characteristic strong smell and somewhat acidic taste. According to a Japanese study, a newly opened can of surströmming has one of the most putrid food smells in the world, stronger than similarly fermented fish dishes such as the Korean hongeo-hoe or Japanese kusaya.

[Ambergris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambergris#Formation) is formed from a secretion of the bile duct in the intestines of the sperm whale. Once expelled by it often floats for years before making landfall. After months to years of photodegradation and oxidation in the ocean the excrement gradually hardens, developing a dark grey or black colour, a crusty and waxy texture. It has a peculiar odour that is at once sweet, earthy, marine, and animalic.

Those are foods which by some definitions sit on the line, but they are not "bad" per se, they are edible; despite being stored in urine or composed of feces and left to rot.

The closest north America gets to food that appears bad is with cheese or sausage which [might be covered in mold](https://www.olympiaprovisions.com/blogs/blog-recipes/lets-learn-about-mold), but this is not rotten, it's a harmless bacteria that prevents the formation of more dangerous bacteria. Since it either passes food inspection or it does not it is either good or bad; not both.

The examples you offered, "honey that has crystalized" and "ice cream that has ice all over it" **can be eaten as-is**. There is nothing that you are required to do to it. Crystallized honey simply has a different texture and icy ice cream is simply ice cream with ice.

Joke: The exception is given by the "[5 second rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-second_rule)". Such food **is** "bad" to eat, but not spoiled or moldy (unless you drop it on mold). There often is no difference in the appearance and even testing might show one such dropped sample is no worse than a sample that was not dropped.

The two concepts "gone bad" and edible are in opposition to each other, like long and short. Even a [freeganist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeganism) makes an effort to avoid "bad food", despite eating out of a dumpster. If it's good to eat it's not bad, if it's bad it's no good to eat.

Comment: Incidentally, something called "edible" is often understood to be edible, but just barely.

Comment: What possessed you to write all this, reiterating the premise of the question without any hint of approaching an answer? Obviously the asker knows "gone bad" implies "not edible"; that's why they asked for a different word that's not "gone bad".

Comment: @Kundor The premise of your question is more applicable to other answers, it's up to you to read to the end.

Comment: @Rob: I did read to the end. At length, you say that "gone bad" implies "not edible", whereas the examples in the question are in fact edible, which is exactly the problem that prompted the original question. After wading through all that, there is no suggested answer whatsoever.

Comment: The very example you offer is explained in my answer and a few of the others, w[e'll help you](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) with this.

Comment: @Rob: I'm legitimately confused what is going on here, since your answer is intelligent and well-written, so I don't see how you are failing to grasp the problem. Everything you wrote is already included in the original post; the issues you point out are exactly what prompted the question. You rehash the issue but do not provide any answer, i.e. a word to describe edible food which is not in the desired state. As far as I can recall, this is the only time I've ever seen such a cogently expressed answer which never got anywhere, hence my questions.

Comment: Quite right, against the binary minds here. Please: Emphasize even more the frame challenge for seeking out an oxymoron for situations culturally defined and 'wrong' use cases for both 'bad' and 'edible'. Surstromming or marmite aren't 'edible' for most. Many traditoinal meats and cheeses are also so well treated, fermented, *aged* and *ripened* that acquired tastes are needed. Leather soles are edible as well, my pica past speaks volumes of praise for this answer!

Comment: @LangLangC It's not so much a dislike of the [complex question fallacy](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/496239/246019) as the answer that was asked for, there are laws against confusion about food safety. People in north American like the [Spanish](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1N6OOWtCYQA) [Inquisition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LnF1OtP2Svk) more than the [Turkish Ice Cream Vendor](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Turkish+ice+cream+spoon+upset).

Answer (score 1):

I'm astonished no one has mentioned **sketchy**.

Sketchy: Merriam Webster online dictionary, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sketchy

> : QUESTIONABLE, IFFY
>   got into a sketchy situation
>   a sketchy character

and in the MW learners dictionary at the same link -

> US, informal : likely to be bad or dangerous

as in this delightful headline -

> Dining Hall Foods Ranked From Most to Least Sketchy

https://spoonuniversity.com/lifestyle/dining-hall-foods-ranked-least-sketchy

Since this is apparently only common in the US, a bit more about the usage seems warranted. *Sketchy* isn't used much for whole foods or raw foods, it is used to refer to cooked or otherwise prepared foods that are understood to have a shortish life after preparation. This could be due to legitimate heath concerns, or just cosmetic issues. Fresh guacamole gets sketchy rather quickly, turning brown on the surface. Tuna salad gets sketchy because food poisoning is a real threat.

> It’s not uncommon for any one of us to have a hospital visit for food poisoning, but eating some **sketchy guacamole** doesn’t come with a 6.7% chance of killing you while medical teams are scrambling to hook you up to a respirator.

https://insh.world/culture/dangerous-foods-around-world/

> I love tuna salad and eat it once a week. Canned Tunafish can be either an awesome healthy choice or flat-out **sketchy** depending on which kind of canned tuna you buy. **Sketchy** for your health and **sketchy** for the environment. So you have to be a label reader!

https://www.healthyseasonalrecipes.com/mediterranean-tuna-salad/

Comment: "The apple is *sketchy*"?  Hmm...maube it's a common expression in the US.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Apples are not terribly difficult to assess and don't usually represent a hazard. It's more applicable to the tuna salad you left in the fridge at work over the weekend.

Comment: I like "iffy" that's something I might say about milk that's just about to go bad/sour. I don't know about sketchy though, I believe it's N.American and I've heard "sketchy" used against a product, a company, a person of questionable morals but not of food. If you can post a source about "sketchy mayonnaise" or "sketchy chicken" etc. I'll upvote it!

Comment: @Mari-LouA done.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst *passed its prime* and *past its best* have both been mentioned, no one has suggested *past its sell-by-date*, for example:

> This mooli/pig's trotter/camembert is past its sell-by-date but I think we can still eat it...

This might be a bit colloquial, but in British-English at least, it is commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is **edible**.

Yes, of course, edible technically also covers food that is in prime condition but there are almost no circumstances under which you would describe such food as "edible". Describing something as edible is [damning it with faint praise](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=damn%20with%20faint%20praise), implying that it can be eaten is about the best that could be said about it.

My only reservation with recommending "edible" is that it can also be applied to food that is badly cooked or prepared such that the best can be said about it is that it is "edible", however I think this should be clear from context. Otherwise I don't think there is a single, generally applicable word; since although words such as stale, soggy, or soured could be used to refer to the problem when referring to specific foods (or drinks) they are not appropriate for all examples.

Comment: _Edible_ can work for the reasons you say, but I wouldn't go so far as to say it's "the word" the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the idiom **"on the turn"**.

I heard this phrase used by a person from the north of England (a "northerner") on a comedy panel quiz on BBC TV.

[Written definition from Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on-the-turn):

> about to go rancid